# Git - How to remove one of two folders with the same name in remote repo

Tags: git, github, directory

I have a repository on github with two folders with the same name but different content. I would like to remove one of these folders. The problem is that if I list the data in the repo locally, there is only one folder (with the content I would like to keep).

Obviously something went wrong in an earlier commit.

Any ideas how I remove one of these folder without removing the other?

Comment: It's supposed to be solved in a case sensitive system like Ubuntu.

Comment: Like i commented below, maybe the issue is that the folder name contains a 'å' (Swedish character)? Being able to push two identical folder names seems weird.

Answer (score 4):

> is that if I list the data in the repo locally, there is only one folder (with the content I would like to keep).

Then it is possible that a git status shows you the second one, deleted.
Or that your OS was not able to load it, because it is case insensitive

Register that deletion to the index, commit and push:

```
git rm --cached -r secondFolder/
git add -A .
git commit -m "delete folder"
git push
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, it does not. "git status" says there is nothing to commit, wokring tree clean. Also, "git pull" generates already up-to-date. Very confusing.

Comment: The folder name contains a 'å' (Swedish character). Could that maybe be part of the problem here?

Comment: It could. Try the `git rm -- cached -r afolder/` (with the special character), to see if you can delete it even though it is not on the disk.